# Having two destination folders using NSIS

Tags: nsis

Currently the product I work on uses NSIS to create it's installer. It works great, we love it.

But now, with some of the issues arising with manipulation of data in program files on Windows 7 and such, we would like to have to separate destination folders during install. One destination will be where all the program files are held, while another would hold any user specific data.

For example:

Program Destination: C:\Program Files\Company\Product

User Data Destination: C:\Company\Product\Data

Obviously we want to give the user a choice of where to put each portion but we can't seem to find a way to create this option in the NSIS installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many directory pages as you want, you probably also want to switch to the PageEx page declaration so you can use the [DirVar](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.15) instruction

Comment: Will this allow me to put both options on the same page or will I be left with 2 separate pages? I'd prefer one page where the user can set both but if this is my only option I suppose I'll have to settle for it.

Comment: @Nedloh If you want both on a single page you have to create a custom page (Use nsDialogs or InstallOptions, both are part of the default NSIS install)

Comment: @Anders What if I want to extract the same file to 2 different destination locations say $INSTDIR and $TEMP, but I just want to embed the file only once in my installer ?

Comment: @foobar: SetOutPath $InstDir, File "foo.bar", SetOutPath $Temp, File "foo.bar"